# Problemas con require_once

Tags: php

Hola chico veréis tengo un código.
Este trozo de codigo requiere de otra pagina donde hay dos funciones
`get_productos()` y `eliminar($_GET['id_eliminar'])`
obtener se llama y carga los productos en la pagina inicial.
Cada registro tiene un botón para eliminar que mediante href envía el id del producto a la pagina con este codigo. Pero el codigo me da error en

```
require_once('modelo/ObtenerRegistro_Modelo.php');
```

El error es:

> Warning: require_once(modelo/ObtenerRegistro_Modelo.php): failed to
>   open stream: No such file or directory in
>   C:\wamp64\www\MVC\controlador\UsoModelo_Controlador.php on

Es raro que la primera vez que pasa por aqui para cargar y mostrar la lista no da un error pero la segunda vez para llamar la funcion eliminar si da error

he probado la funcion `eliminar($_GET['id_eliminar'])` en otro `archivo.php` 
con `require_once('modelo/ObtenerRegistro_Modelo.php');` y funciona no da error.

```
<?php
require_once('modelo/ObtenerRegistro_Modelo.php');

$productos = new ObtenerRegistro_Modelo();
$arrayProductos = $productos->get_productos();

if (isset($_GET['id_eliminar'])) {
    $productos->eliminar($_GET['id_eliminar']);
}    
?>
```

Comment: cual es la ruta que estas parado en tu .php? desde donde llamas al `require_once()`

Comment: Creo que desde aquí puedes obtener la solución: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36577020/php-failed-to-open-stream-no-such-file-or-directory

Comment: Pon `var_dump( __DIR__);` en ambos archivos, comenta la sección que genera error para evitar caídas y compára las salidas. Luego hacer ajustes con secuencias de tipo `../..`

Comment: Tengo una carpeta llamada carpeta1 ,  allí dentro hay un archivo llamado registro.php. Este archivo contiene una clase con dos funciones uno recorre una base de datos otro elimina un registro.Tengo otra carpeta llamada carpeta2 alli dentro un archivo llamado usoCarpeta2.php. Este archivo llama a las dos funciones por eso aquí tengo a   require_once ('carpeta1/registros.php'); . Llama a la primera funcion  que recorre la base de datos nada mas que se ejecute la pagina index.php y muestra en index.php todos los registros.al pinchar sobre el boton eliminar entra otra vez en usoCarpeta2.php.

Comment: Para llamar a la función eliminar vuelve a leer  la linea require_once ('carpeta1/registros.php') y alli es donde peta .Es como que al leer esta linea por segunda  peta . He probado var_dump( __DIR__); El directorio esta bien sobre todo porque ejecuta bien la función que muestra los registros . La función eliminar también esta bien porque  si separo las dos llamadas en archivo diferentes tal y que cuando se llame cada función el programa solo lee una vez require_once ('carpeta1/registros.php');

Comment: Problema solucionado